# Output stream as class member

Tags: c++, class, iostream, output

I have a c++ library that provides an object with complicated logic. During data processing, this object outputs lots of things to std::cout (this is hardcoded now). I would like the processing output not to go to standard output but to a custm widget (some text displaying). I tried to create a `std::ostream` class member, set it with a parameter (std::cout for console application and some other ostream handled inside GUI application). But the compiler throws me following errors:

```
[ 14%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/PietCore.dir/pvirtualmachine.cpp.o
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream: In constructor ‘PVirtualMachine::PVirtualMachine(QString)’:                                                                        
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:363:7: error: ‘std::basic_ostream::basic_ostream() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]’ is protected
/home/tomasz/Development/C++/piet/src/core/pvirtualmachine.cpp:33:50: error: within this context
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ios:45:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iterator:64,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qlist.h:50,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qvector.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qpolygon.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qmatrix.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qtransform.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qimage.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QImage:1,
                 from /home/tomasz/Development/C++/piet/src/core/pcodepointer.h:17,
                 from /home/tomasz/Development/C++/piet/src/core/pblockmanager.h:9,
                 from /home/tomasz/Development/C++/piet/src/core/pvirtualmachine.h:10,
                 from /home/tomasz/Development/C++/piet/src/core/pvirtualmachine.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ios_base.h: In member function ‘std::basic_ios& std::basic_ios::operator=(const std::basic_ios&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ios_base.h:791:5: error: ‘std::ios_base& std::ios_base::operator=(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_ios.h:64:11: error: within this context
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iterator:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qlist.h:50,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qvector.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qpolygon.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qmatrix.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qtransform.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qimage.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QImage:1,
                 from /home/tomasz/Development/C++/piet/src/core/pcodepointer.h:17,
                 from /home/tomasz/Development/C++/piet/src/core/pblockmanager.h:9,
                 from /home/tomasz/Development/C++/piet/src/core/pvirtualmachine.h:10,
                 from /home/tomasz/Development/C++/piet/src/core/pvirtualmachine.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream: In member function ‘std::basic_ostream& std::basic_ostream::operator=(const std::basic_ostream&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:57:11: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios& std::basic_ios::operator=(const std::basic_ios&)’ first required here 
/home/tomasz/Development/C++/piet/src/core/pvirtualmachine.cpp: In member function ‘void PVirtualMachine::setOutput(std::ostream)’:
/home/tomasz/Development/C++/piet/src/core/pvirtualmachine.cpp:216:11: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ostream& std::basic_ostream::operator=(const std::basic_ostream&)’ first required here
```

I'd be glad if someone pointed me out what is wrong, because I've got no idea...

My code looks like this:

- .h file

```
class PVirtualMachine {
  private:
    std::ostream output;
    [...]
  public:
    void setOutput(std::ostream);
    [...]
};
```

- .cpp file

```
void PVirtualMachine::setOutput(std::ostream os)
{
  output = os;
}
```

Comment: `ostream` is not copyable.

Comment: so how can I pass a generic reference to an output stream?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: by using `std::ostream&`, specifically using the `&` after the type (as known as passing by reference).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've got two options here:

- Use references, or
- Use pointers

You can't use normal instances because `ostream` is non-copyable.

**Using references (direct reference to an already-instantiated `ostream`)**

```
class PVirtualMachine {
  private:
    std::ostream & output;
    [...]
  public:
    PVirtualMachine(std::ostream &);  // Reference must be initialized on construction.
    [...]
};
```

*Advantages:*

- No pointer syntax.
- *Should* always refer to a valid instance of `std::ostream`, as long as the original variable is not deleted.

*Disadvantages:*

- The `PVirtualMachine` class must be constructed with the output reference in the initialization list, otherwise it will not compile.
- Cannot change the reference once it has been initialized.
- Cannot work with move-assignment operators (i.e. `operator=(PVirtualMachine &&)`)

**Using pointers (optional reference to object)**

```
class PVirtualMachine {
  private:
    std::ostream * output;
    [...]
  public:
    void setOutput(std::ostream *);
    [...]
};
```

*Advantages:*

- Can be instantiated as a null pointer.
- Can be passed around easily.
- Can be updated to point to a new `std::ostream` instance.
- Can be created internally or externally to the PVirtualMachine instance.
- Works with move-assignment operator.

*Disadvantages:*

- Pointer syntax.
- Must check for null references when accessing the ostream and/or in the constructor.

Comment: The second disadvantage for references should be reflected in the code preceding it. I.e. there should be no `setOutput()` member, instead opting for a construct initializer-list.

Comment: Well you can still set the output later on, but yes, it does need to be constructed initially.

Comment: Once it is construct-initialized (which it *must* be), you cannot change it. references are initialize-only. Thus the need for `setOutput()` goes out the window in the fundamental case.

Comment: @WhozCraig Really? Interesting. I always thought that was possible. I guess I've never tried it! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yeah, no dice. You *can* play the game with things like `std::reference_wrapper<>` if you absolutely *had* to take a reference, but for the case as you presented it, it is construct-init-only.

Comment: In your answer you say: 

`Reference can become invalid if the original instance goes out of scope.`

Don't references keep the instance around even if the original goes out of scope? Where can I find more information about references and when they become invalid?

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey - Variables are not reference counted in C++, so the program does not know how many references point to a variable. When an object instance goes out of scope, all references to it will point to invalid memory. If you need reference counting, you should look at std::shared_ptr. For information on how references are used, check out [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a reference to a `std::ostream` instead, this would support any kind of output stream, e.g. stdout, file, etc. This is fine as long as you only want to use one single stream, and the stream doesn't get destroyed:

```
class PVirtualMachine {
  private:
    std::ostream & output;
    [...]
  public:
    PVirtualMachine(std::ostream & os = std::cout): output(os) { }
    // void setOutput(std::ostream & os) { output = os; } // can't change the reference
    [...]
};
```

If you want this class to share the stream (therefore keeping it alive for this class's lifetime), use a `std::shared_ptr<std::ostream>` instead of a reference.

Comment: /home/tomasz/Development/C++/piet/src/core/pvirtualmachine.cpp:33:1: error: uninitialized reference member ‘PVirtualMachine::output’ [-fpermissive] - so I have to pass it in constructor's initializing list?

Comment: Sure thing. I'd probably use a `std::reference_wrapper<>` and bind it to  the given stream reference if it was absolutely mandatory we take a reference *and* the lifetime of the reference outside the object instance is known to exceed the object itself (like cout likely will, for example, etc). but the concept is the same regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use an ostream instance in the module I might want to debug. Note that there is no default constructor for this type, you have to pass a pointer to a streambuffer, but that pointer can be null. Now, when/if you want to capture the module's output, you just attach a streambuffer to it using `rdbuf()`. This streambuffer can be std::cout's streambuffer, but it can also be a `std::stringbuf` or `std::filebuf` or some self-written one that automatically redirects the output to some window. One caveat: Output without streambuffer will set the failbit (or even badbit?) so you have to call `clear()` on the output stream after changing the streambuffer. Also note that you must manually manage the lifetime of this streambuffer and the streams referencing it, there is no ownership transfer and automatic cleanup involved.